# Unable to see where the error come from in production mode

Tags: angular, angular7, production-environment

In **developement environment no error** is trought by explorer console but serving application in any other environment mode I'm getting these two errors:

[image]

I don't know where could come from the errors because there are no reference to TypeScript file and  it's happening in some parts of the app.

*NOTE: To reproduce the error in local I'm serving the app using this command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve -c production
```

How could I see the source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **angular.json** file I have modified the configuration section to see the file where error come from in the explorer console. Just setting ***sourceMap = true***

```
"configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "optimization": true,
                        "outputHashing": "all",
                        "sourceMap": true,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": false,
                        "aot": true,
                        "extractLicenses": true,
                        "vendorChunk": true,
                        "buildOptimizer": true,
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src-admin/../src-common/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src-admin/../src-common/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

The error was a silly mistake that has been solved with a simple validation. (An object expected as observable was *undefined*)